# Is the first-order theory of the class of free monoids finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: logic, model-theory, monoid

I asked long ago whether the class $C$ of free monoids is a first-order axiomatizable class. The answer was no. However, the class $C$ does have an associated first-order theory $Th(C)$. Is that theory finitely axiomatizable? If so, what additional axioms do we need to add to the axioms for monoids to axiomatize that theory?

Comment: Well, at the very least, left and right divisibility should be partial orderings (i.e. antisymmetric) and every nonidentity element should be left and right divisible by an irreducible (not necessarily the same one)